# a error in kmeans clustering by mahout on hadoop

Tags: hadoop, native, mahout

I got a error when run kmeans clustering by mahout on hadoop, after checking the error log, I thought it maybe caused by hadoop native library,but when I had compiled the hadoop again by myself, and then go to run the job, it always throw out the hs_err_pid*.log, its content is as follows:strong text

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x00002aae75c8168f, pid=30832, tid=1076017472
#
# JRE version: 6.0_29-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.4-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x868f]  double+0xcf
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000040115000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=30863, stack(0x000000004012b000,0x000000004022c000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGFPE: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (FPE_INTDIV), si_addr=0x00002aae75c8168f

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000f4d007f, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000040227d00, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x0000000040227ba0, RBP=0x0000000040227d40, RSI=0x000000000f4d007f, RDI=0x00002aaab90008f1
R8 =0x00002aaab8e694c0, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0xffffffffffffffff
R12=0x0000000040227d00, R13=0x00002aaab8e69210, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x00002aaab90002c0
RIP=0x00002aae75c8168f, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x0000000000000000

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+300
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+347
j  java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+54
j  java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.<clinit>()V+25
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory.<clinit>()V+13
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec.getCompressorType()Ljava/lang/Class;+4
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/compress/Comp
ressor;+4
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/compress/Compressor;+2
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/l
ang/Class;ZLorg/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$Metadata;)V+121
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$RecordCompressWriter.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Ljava/lang/Class
;Ljava/lang/Class;ISJLorg/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$Metadata;)V+30
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Cla
ss;ISJLorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$CompressionType;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Progressable;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$Me
tadata;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$Writer;+100
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Cla
ss;Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$CompressionType;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$Writer;+43
j  org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Cla
ss;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/SequenceFile$Writer;+10
j  org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.RandomSeedGenerator.buildRandom(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;ILorg/apache/mah
out/common/distance/DistanceMeasure;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;+101
j  org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+264
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Lorg/apache/hadoop/util/Tool;[Ljava/lang/String;)I+38
j  org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+15
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+538
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub



    Is there anyone can help me or give me some advice?

    xianwu
```

Comment: It can't find the zlib libraries, are they installed?

Comment: I would agree with @ThomasJungblut - but i think the libraries are there (otherwise you'd see a different error message), just they are probably corrupt in some way - have you tried to re-compile the native libraries recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can help you to make some sense of this problem as below:

If you work on your stack and see the last call made with Hadoop Libraries in your stack is as below:

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader
```

Now if you look at the source code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.hudson.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.19.1/org/apache/hadoop/util/NativeCodeLoader.java) you will see the code is trying to load a Hadoop Library as below:

```
41   try {
42      System.loadLibrary("hadoop");
43      LOG.info("Loaded the native-hadoop library");
44      nativeCodeLoaded = true;
45    } catch (Throwable t) {
46      // Ignore failure to load
47      LOG.debug("Failed to load native-hadoop with error: " + t);
48      LOG.debug("java.library.path=" + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
49    }
```

Now if you look your call stack you will see exact same thing the Java run time is trying to load a library and then the crash occurred:

```
Java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+300
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+347
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+54
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.<clinit>()V+25
```

So the problem is exactly related with Java Run time and there is not a lot you can do. You sure can log this error and go ahead and try to test again your code. Such problem could occur time to time and you just keep going on for the next.

Comment: Thank you for your replying, Avkash. Because I didn't change any codes of hadoop and mahout, instead, I only call the jar package(mahout-core-0.5.job) on hadoop(hadoop-0.20.203.0); As you word, the problem could occur time to time, so I need to fix it clearly. I will try reinstall the java or upgrade the present java to upper level. please give your advice. Thanks. --xianwu

Comment: Try using Java 7 which is compatible with recently available Hadoop and Mahout binaries.

Comment: That's fine, I used java 7, and run it normally, thanks Avkash.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with Hadoop or Mahout really. The JVM itself crashed. It's a bug in the JVM, or a problem with your JVM installation. Try again, and/or reinstall Java.

Comment: Thank you for your replying, Owen.My command is :bin/hadoop jar mahout-core-0.5-job.jar org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver --input /user/ppstat/jixianwu/clustering_test/pipi_vectors --output /user/ppstat/jixianwu/clustering_test/kmeans-clusters2 --distanceMeasure org.apache.mahout.common.distance.CosineDistanceMeasure --clusters /user/ppstat/jixianwu/clustering_test/initial-clusters --numClusters 10 --convergenceDelta 0.01 --maxIter 20 --tempDir /user/ppstat/jixianwu/clustering_tes/temp/2012-05-02;  so, I agree with you, because I didn't change any codes. I will try upper JVM,Thx